# Set a landing page for www. prefix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

So I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.al4.co.nz/2011/05/setting-up-a-secure-ubuntu-lamp-server/) to set up my webpage.
I was able to set a landing page for "`example.com`" but "`www.example.com`" is still the default apache landing page. Could anyone help me out?

Here is my folder strucure:

```
srv -> www -> example.com -> index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line in the Apache default site or VHost configuration where your landing site is, for:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

Then when requests for www.example.com arrive, Apache will use that config to serve them as well.

Comment: Also check the dns records, they both shouldp point to the same server...